# Change cursor for the duration of a thread

Tags: winapi, mfc

In an MFC application I want to show the wait cursor (hour glass) for as long as a thread is running, but calling

```
SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
```

from inside the static ThreadProc member function doesn't have any effect. Any help?

Thanks, RSel

**Edit**

Figured it out. This is one way to do it:

Call LoadCursor in the constructor:

```
m_cursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT);
```

Call SetCursor right before AfxBeginThread:

```
SetCursor(m_cursor);
AfxBeginThread( ... );
```

Overwrite OnSetCursor to prevent the cursor from changing back prematurely:

```
CMyView::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{   
    if (m_thread_is_running)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return CView::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Effect is explained here.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/25/421707.aspx

Comment: According to my `OnSetCursor` it returns a `BOOL`. Also, it looks like we should return `TRUE` to halt processing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked, but I think that the cursor is updated every time the mouse moves. So you would either call SetCursor() every time you get a WM_SETCURSOR message or you change the default cursor. Note that you should not call LoadCursor() every time you set the cursor.

The default cursor is set in the [WNDCLASS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct of a window.

See [WM_SETCURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648382%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Call it form the main thread when you start the thread then PostMessage a custom message to the main thread when the thread exits and disable the hour glass on that message.

Comment: I tried that already, i.e. calling SetCursor right before AfxBeginThread. The cursor switches back to the default immediately after AfxBeginThread returns.