# changing mouse cursor to wait cursor then starting worker thread and changing back on thread completion

Tags: c++, mfc, mouse-cursor

In an older MFC application I have to perform a network connect request to another computer which may take a number of seconds in the case of incorrect computer name before the request times out. So I am starting up a worker thread to make the initial connection so that the user interface is still responsive.

The network connect request is triggered by the user selecting a menu item which brings up a dialog to fill in the target computer information. When the user clicks the Ok button on the dialog, the network connection request is processed using the worker thread.

What I want to do is to change the mouse cursor to a wait indicator and then remove the wait indicator once the connection is actually made or the attempt times out.

What I am running into is that the mouse cursor is remaining a pointer and the mouse cursor is not changing to a wait indicator.

What I originally thought was that I could just change the mouse cursor using the `BeginWaitCursor()` function. However that has no effect that I can see.

Further reading indicates that I also need to have an override of the `afx_msg BOOL OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)` method of the `CScrollView` class however I can't seem to find anything helpful that describes what I need to do in that method. The `OnSetCursor()` method seems to be called for a variety of reasons and just moving the mouse causes a breakpoint in that method to be triggered.

It looks like that in the `OnSetCursor()` method I should detect the current application state and based on that use the `SetCursor()` function to set one of the possible mouse cursor styles which have been previously loaded with `LoadCursor()`. See [Prevent MFC application to change cursor back to default icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170858/prevent-mfc-application-to-change-cursor-back-to-default-icon) as well as [Change cursor for the duration of a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369244/change-cursor-for-the-duration-of-a-thread)

However I am unsure at to whether that is how it is actually done and what the parameters that are provided with the `OnSetCursor()` actually mean and how to use them.

In the second of the two above SO postings it appears a global is being used to decide if the default `CView::OnSetCursor()` method is being called or not.

Comment: Have you tried [`CWaitCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwaitcursor-class)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I just tried it and what I found is that it does change the mouse cursor to a waiting indication. However there is a local scope requirement which means as soon as the menu handler starts the worker thread and then returns, the `CWaitCursor` object goes out of scope. I found that if I use `BeginWaitCursor()` and then put a sleep after starting the worker thread, freezing the UI, I see the mouse cursor waiting indication as well. So it appears that in addition to `BeginWaitCursor()` there is something else I need to do to keep the cursor as a waiting cursor.

Comment: You can dynamically create the `CWaitCursor` object, but since your main message thread keeps running that might replace the cursor anyway.  How do you handle the user picking another menu option (or some other interaction) while you're trying to get the network connection?  You might need to resort to the "Connecting to server" app modal dialog.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm until the connection is made and is up, most of the menu items are disabled and grayed out. About the only thing the user can do until the connection exists is to exit. What is the "Connecting to server" app modal dialog? This application is using UDP to "connect" to the target computer which really involves informing the target server that a new communication session needs to be created and to provide the token needed for using the new session. All communication is over UDP and not TCP.

Comment: You create the wait cursor, create a dialog or window with some sort of message that is app modal (which keeps input from the rest of your app), and possibly with a "cancel" button.  Close the dialog once the connection is made and your thread terminates.

Comment: Do you want to change the cursor for the whole application or for some specific window?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ok, I see. As part of handling the menu item to make a connection, the application throws up a modal dialog for the connection data entry, takes the input if the Ok button was clicked and then do the connection. The change would be change the dialog with a "Connect" button and do the connection thread start in the modal dialog. Then either handle the connect ready message or allow pressing the "Cancel" button to kill the thread and pop down the modal dialog box with an error indication.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I plan to change the cursor for the whole application. Why do you ask?

Comment: Maybe use `OnSetCursor()` for the main frame-window then.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I've been unable to find a viable example of how to do that. The second posting seems to be the best example however I'm not sure if that is a good example to actually follow or not. Do you have an opinion about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First declare the following global variables:

```
BOOL bConnecting = FALSE; // TRUE if connecting, set by your application
HCURSOR hOldCursor = NULL; // Cursor backup
```

When you need to display the hourglass cursor call:

```
bConnecting = TRUE;
hOldCursor = SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
```

Once the connection is established (or failed) call:

```
bConnecting = FALSE;
SetCursor(hOldCursor);
// Alternatively you can call SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)); - no need to backup the cursor then
// Or even not restore the cursor at all, it will be reset on the first WM_MOUSEMOVE message (after bConnecting is set to FALSE)
```

You also need to override `OnSetCursor()`:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
    if (bConnecting) return TRUE; // Prevent MFC changing the cursor

    // else call the default
    return CFrameWndEx::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
}
```

And add the `ON_WM_SETCURSOR()` directive to the message map for `CMainFrame` in order to enable the `OnSetCursor()` message handler.

The "main-frame" is the parent of all windows in an MFC Application, and that's why we override `OnSetCursor()` for it. It affects all other windows.

In the MFC environment you can also use the `BeginWaitCursor()`, `RestoreWaitCursor()`, and `EndWaitCursor()` functions. These are `CCmdTarget` methods and can be accessed using `AfxGetApp()` as well as any `CWnd` derived class.

Note that using a global variable in a multi-threaded environment with both UI thread and worker threads, depending on how the global is used and accessed by the threads, you may create a race condition.

Comment: The reason why setting the wait cursor (anyway if by BeginWaitCursor() or by CWaitCursor) isn't sufficient is that you are processing the message queue afterwars. While the message queue is running, the window below the mouse cursor gets a WM_SETCURSOR event for mouse moves to give that window a chance to control the cursor above it.


If the window's thread (so usually the main thread) is busy, setting the wait cursor once will leave this cursor visible until resetting it or until the WM_SETCURSOR is processed.

Comment: @Nick: Exactly, the problem is that MFC does process the WM_SETCURSOR message, so we need to provide an override. In many code samples I have seen calling `SetCursor()` wihtin `OnSetCursor()` (processes the WM_SETCURSOR message) which gets called even for mouse moves. Instead, in the solution I suggested above I set it only once, and then simply return TRUE (prevent changing it back), until it is reset. That is, `OnSetCursor()` may be called, but it won't do anything, and returning TRUE will prevent the system sending it to other windows. The ownign thread does not necessarily need to be busy.

Comment: @Richard Chambers: Thanks for editing my answer. Concerning your message-map note, the Properties/Events Editor in Visual Studio normally does this for you (adds the declaration and the implementation AND modifies the message-map), so the procedure is quite automated. This is the way most developers use it, and that's why I didn't mention it specifically. As for the multi-threaded environment, indeed, accessing/modifying global variables from different threads requires interlocked or synchronized access.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou your posted answer helped me out. As I was working with my source implementing your proposed solution, I ran into a few things which is where the edits came from. I added them to your post just to be complete. So many other answers are just half way and I wanted to have at least one on this subject and in this area that was reasonably complete.

Answer (score 2):

@Constantine's OnSetCursor implementation didn't work for me (VC++ 2013; Win 10) - wait cursor still went back to arrow after starting a thread. But I resolved my issue with following code.

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
    if (bConnecting) {
          SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
          return TRUE; // Prevent MFC changing the cursor
    }
    // else call the default
    return CFrameWndEx::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
}
```

Note that that all opened dialogs or views should have the OnSetCursor if you want to display wait cursor when hovering on the views.